# Librosa and Numba in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numba, librosa

I am experiencing the numba to speed up my codes, I encounter an error in this code

```
@njit
def fee(x):
    chroma_stft = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=data, sr=sampling_rate).ravel()
    return(chroma_stft)
```

`TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Unknown attribute 'chroma_stft' of type Module(<module 'librosa.feature' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/librosa/feature/__init__.py'>)`

How to solve this, and is there any way to use scipy.stats functions in numba?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@njit
```

is shorthand for

```
@jit(nopython=True)
```

which does not allow importing of Python code. Change it to

```
@jit
```

and it should work.

But needless to say [you will not gain any performance improvement](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#will-numba-work-for-my-code).

Comment: Sir, IS there any other way to increase the speed of the code, I am running in google colab

Comment: Are you calling `chroma_stft` for each frame or each audio file?

Comment: yes, Sir, I calling chroma_stft for all the audio files

Comment: So once per file? Then I don't see any trivial performance improvement tricks. And this is also beyond the scope of the original question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that Numba is not able to JIT the function in [nopython (`@jit(nopython=True)`)](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode) mode (which `@njit` is an alias for).

You'll need to use regular `@jit`, but the speedups will very likely not be as drastic.

The same stands for `scipy.stats`, most likely.

Comment: I tried with @jit, the speed is same as in CPU

Comment: What to do to increase the speed, I have thousands of data that needs to calculate chroma_stft, Sir, Is there any other way...

Comment: Do the data depend on each other? If not, you can use `multiprocessing` to (try to) use all of the CPUs on your machine. Other than that, (a) get a faster/bigger machine (b) accept that it's going to take some time (c) rewrite your code in a faster/lower-level language